# MSBuild 4.0 asking for Microsoft sdk v7.0a

Tags: sdk, msbuild

How do I find Microsoft sdk v7.0A online to download, I am trying to run msbuild without have visual studio and the project keeps asking for that specific sdk, or how do I change the project to accept differnt sdks

Comment: would be useful if you share your msbuild script. You might have targets that reference Microsoft SDK 7.0

Comment: dont know what that is?, what do I need to download to a fresh machine just to run the msbuild without visual studio?

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to say is that MSBuild runs fines without Platform SDK. It is the scripts that you running that requires SDK. Visual Studio install some part of SDK as part of installation.

Comment: I have a VM, where VS 2010 is not installed I copied the whole sdk folder and put registry keys on that machine, then I do a build, it errors out saying that the resgen.exe cannot be found in the Microsoft SDK path even thou it is in all the folders, I didnt download and install the sdk just copied the folder over,